# How to get timestamp of block in action logic like in ethereum

Tags: eosio.token, eosio.cdt, eosio-cpp

is there a way to find the time stamp of the block in which the transaction was mined like in solidity we can use block.timestamp.
Can I have code examples of finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the developers portal for the details on the EOSIO API:

https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/nodeos/plugins/chain_api_plugin/api-reference/index

Comment: Thanks, for any one in the future the answer to this is to use eosio::current_block_time().to_time_point().sec_since_epoch() to get time stamp in uint32_t type, remove sec_since_epoch() to get data in time_point data type.